# time.Parse in Go with varying fractional second length

Tags: go, time, timestamp, datetime-parsing

I am parsing a timestamp from a DB.  My layout is the following:

```
layout = "2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000 -0700 MST"

pipelineTS, err := time.Parse(layout, rawPipelineTS)
```

The issue is that sometimes the fractional seconds are not 9 digits, for example:

```
2018-12-18 15:25:08.73728596 +0000 UTC
```

When it finds a value like this, it errors out.  Any ideas on how to fix this?  The timestamps come from a DB table.  I need it to take any number of fractional second digits.

Answer (score 9):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> A decimal point followed by one or more zeros represents a fractional
>   second, printed to the given number of decimal places. A decimal point
>   followed by one or more nines represents a fractional second, printed
>   to the given number of decimal places, with trailing zeros removed.

---

Use nines, not zeros, for the layout fractional seconds.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"

    input := "2018-12-18 15:25:08.73728596 +0000 UTC" // 8 digits
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, input)
    fmt.Println(t, err)

    input = "2018-12-18 15:25:08.7372 +0000 UTC" // 4 digits
    t, err = time.Parse(layout, input)
    fmt.Println(t, err)

    input = "2018-12-18 15:25:08 +0000 UTC" // 0 digits
    t, err = time.Parse(layout, input)
    fmt.Println(t, err)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/j4WBmz3ENke

Output:

```
2018-12-18 15:25:08.73728596 +0000 UTC <nil>
2018-12-18 15:25:08.7372 +0000 UTC <nil>
2018-12-18 15:25:08 +0000 UTC <nil>
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [`time.Parse`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Parse) docs:

> When parsing (only), the input may contain a fractional second
> field immediately after the seconds field, even if the layout does not
> signify its presence. In that case either a comma or a decimal point
> followed by a maximal series of digits is parsed as a fractional second.
> Fractional seconds are truncated to nanosecond precision.

For time parsing:

1. If you don't specify fractional seconds in the layout, `time.Parse` will still accept it in the input, with full resolution (the "maximal series of digits"). ([source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.20/src/time/format.go#L1159-L1164))
2. If you specify fractional seconds with one or more zeros, `time.Parse` requires the input to have that exact number of fractional digits. ([source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.20/src/time/format.go#L1271-L1277))
3. If you specify fractional seconds with one or more nines, `time.Parse` actually accepts **any number** of fractional digits (up to 9) in the input. That is, the behavior is the same as if you didn't specify fractional seconds at all (case #1). I think the docs are not clear on this point at all, but for parsing (not formatting), `.9`, `.99`, `.999`, `.999999`, etc. are all exactly equivalent. ([source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.20/src/time/format.go#L1286-L1291))

   If the input contains more than 9 fractional digits, Go 1.19 and below return an error, while Go 1.20 ignores any fractional digits beyond the 9th ("truncate[s] to nanosecond precision"). ([source](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/4e9183cb14bf58011389c8a8c8ccaecd3ef50451))

Playground samples: https://go.dev/play/p/-aE8T9DchlQ